# What does the icon next to the player's name mean in Wormnet?

Tags: worms-armageddon

In Worms Armageddon, when you're playing online via Wormnet, there is an icon displayed next to your name and country flag. Usually, it is a bronze medal in the shape of a chevron. What does this icon represent, and how do you change it?

[image: Screenshot of Wormnet interface]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Worms Knowledge Base](http://worms2d.info/WormNET_(Worms_Armageddon)) :

> At the moment of writing this article, the rank and login system has been removed from *WormNET*, because it has been abused several years ago.

You won't be able to change your rank on any official server.